# Javascript:Undefined value for particular row

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I am error on javascript

> value is undefined

I am doing calculations on the basis of Styleclass on row wise. So i am doing like following code .

```
function onChangeFactor(val,idx)
   {
    var Factor=val;
    var FunderList=document.getElementsByClassName('FundedOfferClass');
    var PaybackList=document.getElementsByClassName('PaybackOfferClass');
    console.log('-------> IDX'+idx);
     var Funded=FunderList[idx].value;// getting error on this line
     Funded=Funded.replace(/,/g,''); 

      if(Funded!=null || Factor !=null){
            var Payback= (parseFloat(Funded)*parseFloat(Factor)).toFixed(2);
              PaybackList[idx].value=Payback;

         }
         if(isNaN(Payback)){
              PaybackList[idx].value=0;
         } 

   }

 <apex:column headerValue="Terms(In Days)">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.Terms_In_Months__c}" styleClass="offerTermClass" id="OfferTerm" rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}" onchange="onChangeTerm(this.value)"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.Terms_In_Months__c}"  rendered="{!O.IsEditable}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Funding Amount">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.Funding_Amount__c}" styleClass="FundedOfferClass" id="FundedOffer" rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}" onchange="onChangeFunded(this.value);"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.Funding_Amount__c}"   rendered="{!O.IsEditable}"/>
              </apex:column>
               <apex:column headerValue="Factor Rate"> 
                  <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.Factor_Rate__c}" styleClass="FactorOfferClass" id="FactorRate"  rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}" onchange="onChangeFactor(this.value,{!O.Index});" />
                  <apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.Factor_Rate__c}"  rendered="{!O.IsEditable}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Payback Amount">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.Payback_Amount__c}" styleClass="PaybackOfferClass" id="PaybackOffer"  rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}" html-disabled="true"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.Payback_Amount__c}"  rendered="{!O.IsEditable}"/>
              </apex:column>
```

How can we solve this issue?